# How to have a file Import Button in Mathematica

Tags: dynamic, import

so I've been having trouble getting a dynamic import button to work inside of a manipulate. I have code that takes in a data set (in this case an excel sheet), and I got everything to work fine in the UI at first. But there are some days where my code simply seems not to work.

```
    Manipulate[DataModelGenerator[data1, Temperature, Rate, 
   alphaseed,  Qseed, Aseed, nseed], Dynamic[Button["import data",   fileFull = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]; 
   data1 = Flatten[Import[fileFull], 1]], data1], {Temperature, InputField}, {Rate, InputField},  Grid[{{"Seed Values"}, {Grid[{{"Q", 
   Control@{{Qseed, 18, ""}, 
     ControlType -> InputField}}, {"A", 
   Control@{{Aseed, 29, ""}, 
     ControlType -> InputField}}, {"n", 
   Control@{{nseed, 2, ""}, 
     ControlType -> InputField}}, {"\[Alpha]", 
   Control@{{alphaseed, 1, ""}, 
     ControlType -> InputField}}}]}}]
 , ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

For UI purposes I would prefer to have the button with the manipulate controls. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What when you add `Method->"Queued"` to the `Button`? p.s. it seems `Dynamic` on `Button` is not needed.

Comment: @Kuba `Method->"Queued"` without `Dynamic` works great on Windows 7, Mathematica 10.4.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a FileNameSetter to first select the file, then a button to import the data. For example:

```
Manipulate[
     DataModelGenerator[data1, Temperature, Rate, alphaseed, Qseed, Aseed,nseed], Row[{Item[FileNameSetter[Dynamic[selectedFile]], Alignment -> Center], 
   Button["Import", 
    data1 = Flatten[Import[selectedFile], 1]]}], {Temperature,InputField}, {Rate, InputField}, 
   Grid[{{"Seed Values"}, {Grid[{{"Q", 
    Control@{{Qseed, 18, ""}, ControlType -> InputField}}, {"A", 
    Control@{{Aseed, 29, ""}, ControlType -> InputField}}, {"n", 
    Control@{{nseed, 2, ""}, 
     ControlType -> InputField}}, {"\[Alpha]", 
   Control@{{alphaseed, 1, ""}, ControlType -> InputField}}}]}}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```